# Simple Javascript Function - 2 Choices, each going to a different URL

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to have a Confirm/Decline box pop up when someone clicks a link. When they click "Ok" it takes them to one place, when they click "Cancel" it takes them to another place. Most of my experience is with PHP but usually I can take other JavaScript functions and make them work... can't seem to figure this one out though.

Here's my script:

```
function confirmChoice(name, newid){
    answer = confirm("Transfer Ownership of this task to " + name + 
                     "? Press Cancel to decline.")
    if (answer == 1) {
        location = "transfer.php?task=<? echo $taskid; ?>&from=<? echo ownerid; ?>&to=" + newid;
    } elseif (answer==0) {
        location = "decline.php?task=<? echo $taskid; ?>";
    }   
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Okay, changed the code as suggested. Now it is:

```
function confirmChoice(name, newid){
var answer = confirm("Transfer Ownership of this task to " + name + "? Press Cancel to decline.")
if (answer){
location = "transfer.php?task=<? echo $thistaskid; ?>&from=<? echo $ownerid; ?>&to=" + newid;
}else{
location="decline.php?task=<? echo $thistaskid; ?>";
}   
}
```

And the link used is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="confirmChoice(<? echo $requestorname; ?>, <? echo $newid; ?>); return false;"><? echo $requestorname; ?> Requested Ownership</a>
```

I still don't get a confirm box...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it `top.location` instead of just `location`

Also, I would recommend not doing `answer == 1` for the comparison.

`confirm` returns a boolean value anyway. Just do `if (answer) {`

The reason for avoiding `answer == 1` is that doing `== 1` is a non strict comparison and it will eventually bite you if you are not aware of how JavaScript behaves. `answer === true` is an acceptable way of doing this too.

Another important detail is that when you do this:

```
answer = confirm("something here");
```

You are declaring answer as a global variable. This is terrible practice and you should avoid it. Just add `var` before it to fix it.

```
var answer = confirm("whatever");
```

For more information on javascript comparisons: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: Hmm thanks, but that still didn't work.. I get no Confirm box.

Comment: Chances are your function is never being called. You will have to provide other code before I can help.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I made the changes you suggested. The link on the page is <a href="#" onclick="confirmChoice(--NAME--, --ID--); return false;">--NAME-- Requested Ownership</a>

Comment: Just to be sure. are you doing it like this? onclick="confirmChoice('some name', 123); return false;" because the single quotes for the name are important

Comment: Glad! As an extra, you might want to escape that $requestorname to avoid XSS vulnerabilities. Use htmlentities for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using window.open(), you can easily change where that destination is but checking what the confirm returned.

```
var res = confirm("Do you agree?");
```

and do your traffic direction accordingly

```
var options = ['http://google.com', 'http://boston.com'];
window.location = options[ res ? 1 : 0 ];
// or
window.open = options[ res ? 1 : 0 ];
```

The fiddle doesnt want to play nice but it works for me on my local machine.
http://jsfiddle.net/kyleouellette/G9KGm/1/